# HY093 Error PDO dropdown list of available rooms

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Please help, trying to create a booking form where the user will get a dropdown list of available rooms with the capacity stated in the field above.

I'm new to PDO and trying to learn but can't seem to find the answer on my own.

ATM, the dropdown list says "NOTICE: Undefined index: ... on line 29 ... SQLSTATE(HY093)"

line 29 is: `$group = $_GET['groupsize'];`
 Tried a lot of different values and keep getting errors with the list.

```
<input type="text" name="groupsize"><br>



<select id="roomID" name="roomID">                      
<option value="">
<?php 
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=reserve", 'root', '');

    $group = $_GET['groupsize'];

    $ROOMS = $DBH->prepare("SELECT ROOM_NAME FROM room WHERE capacity = :group");
    $ROOMS->execute();

    $ROOMS->bindParam(':group', $group);

    while($result = fetchAll($ROOMS)){
        echo '<OPTION VALUE="$result[0]">"$result[]"</OPTION>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$ROOMS = $DBH->prepare("SELECT ROOM_NAME FROM room WHERE capacity = :group");
$ROOMS->execute();

$ROOMS->bindParam(':group', $group);
```

To

```
$ROOMS = $DBH->prepare("SELECT ROOM_NAME FROM room WHERE capacity = :group");
$ROOMS->bindValue(':group', $group);
$ROOMS->execute();
```

Comment: NOTICE: Undefined index: groupsize in ..... on line 29 (same as earlier) Fatal error: Call to undefined function fetchAll() on line 35 (this is the while loop)

Comment: Have you got groupsize declared in `GET` (I.E. in the address bar, page.php?groupsize=x?) I'm guessing no, and I'm guessing that you haven't got it in `POST` either since I can see the input called groupsize

Answer (score 0):

This is my whole booking.php files body content. Tried a few things and got the error away but then the dropdown list did not show anything.

As i said, im new to this so might be simple but i can't see it :/

```
<form action="reservation.php" method="_POST">
Dato:<br>
<input type="date" name="date"><br>
Fra:<br>
<input type="time" name="start"><br>
Til:<br>
<input type="time" name="endT"><br>
Tittel for booking:<br>
<input type="text" name="title"><br>
Ditt brukernavn (8 tegn):<br>
<input type="text" name="userID"><br>
Gruppestørrelse:<br>
<input type="text" name="groupsize"><br>
Velg tilgjengelig rom:<br>

<select id="roomID" name="roomID">                      
<option value="">
<?php 
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=reserve", 'root', '');

    $group = $_GET['groupsize'];

    $ROOMS = $DBH->prepare("SELECT ROOM_NAME FROM room WHERE capacity = :group");
    $ROOMS->bindValue(':group', $group);
    $ROOMS->execute();

    if($ROOMS->rowCount() > 0){
        echo '<OPTION VALUE="$result[0]">"$result[]"</OPTION>';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Ingen rom tilgjengelig.';
    }
?>
</select><br><br><br>


<!--<select name="roomID"></select><br> -->

<input type="reset" value="tilbakestill"><input type="submit" value="Send booking">
```

Comment: reservation.php are doing the reservation after the whole form is filled out btw.